# Linked Binary Tree and removing a Leaf

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree

At the moment I'm doing a project and seems I can't get past the Logic.

What's the best way to delete a leaf? At the moment I'm falling into an NullPointerException and don't know why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
@Override
    public E removeLeaf(Position<E> p){
        BinaryTreeNode<E> node = ((BinaryTreeNode<E>) p);
        E element = node.element();
        if(node.left != null && node.right != null) throw new InvalidPositionException();
        node.parent.left = null;
        node.parent.right = null;
        return element;
    }
```

Code Below is my testing class

```
public class BinaryTreeTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedBinaryTree<Integer> numTree = new LinkedBinaryTree<>();
        Position<Integer> nroot = numTree.addRoot(1);
        System.out.println(numTree.toString());
        Position<Integer> nchild1 = numTree.insertChild(nroot, 6);
        System.out.println(numTree.toString());
        Position<Integer> nchild2 = numTree.insertChild(nroot, 7);
        Position<Integer> nchild11 = numTree.insertChild(nchild1, 8);
        Position<Integer> nchild12 = numTree.insertChild(nchild1, 23);
        Position<Integer> nchild20 = numTree.insertChild(nchild12, 11);
        Position<Integer> nchild21 = numTree.insertChild(nchild12, 21);
        System.out.println(numTree.toString());

        numTree.removeLeaf(nchild20);

        System.out.println(numTree.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, add an exception stacktrace to your post. It will help to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues in the following snippet of code:

```
if(node.left != null && node.right != null) throw new InvalidPositionException();
node.parent.left = null;
node.parent.right = null;
```

The first line seems to test whether the node is really a *leaf*, but the logic is wrong. It currently tests whether the node has two children, but it should even reject the situation where it has one child. So the `&&` should be an `||`.

The other two lines clear the links with *two* child nodes, while it should only detach the current node, and not its sibling. So you need to find out whether the current node is the left or right child of its parent, and only clear that link:

```
if (node.left != null || node.right != null) throw new InvalidPositionException();
if (node.parent.left == node) {
    node.parent.left = null;
} else {
    node.parent.right = null;
}
```

This still does not deal well with the boundary case where the node is the root itself (the last node in the tree). In that case `parent` will probably be `null` (it depends on your implementation). So you would need to add a condition for that. And if you have a reference `root` to the root node of the tree, then that `root` should be cleared:

```
if (node.left != null || node.right != null) throw new InvalidPositionException();
if (node.parent == null) {
    root = null; // this assumes you have such a variable...
} else if (node.parent.left == node) {
    node.parent.left = null;
} else {
    node.parent.right = null;
}
```